# Region dummy Variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dummy-variable

I think my questions is not so hard to answer, but I could not find any solution so far. So I thought I will ask it myself.

I have a Pen World Table pwt100, where a lot of data is connected to countries. However I want to make dummy variables for different regions of the world. For instance, latin America, south asia, middle east, etc.

I tried the following:

```
Latin_America = c('Belize','Costa Rica','El Salvador','Guatemala','Honduras',
                  'Mexico','Nicaragua','Panama','Argentina','Bolivia','Brazil',
                  'Chile','Colombia','Ecuador', 'French Guiana','Guyana','Paraguay','Peru',
                  'Suriname','Uruguay','Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)',
                  'Dominican Republic','Haiti')

df$Dummy_LatinAmerica <- ifelse(df$country == Latin_America , 1, 0)
```

But that gives an error: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I simply cant find the answer anywhere, so maybe someone can help me :)

Comment: Try `%in%` instead of `==`. Even better, `as.integer(df$country %in% Latin_America)`.

Comment: @RonakShah Same comments... And [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090114/r-pair-wise-product-of-unknown-number-of-vectors-matrices) :)

Comment: Thinking alike, that is 2nd time within 5 mins ;-)